# Strange behavior with BeautifulSoup find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using the following code to find all the rowspan="7" in the source code corresponding to the following web page.

```
http://www.sebi.gov.in/sebiweb/investment/FIILatestSE.jsp?period=month
```

The surprise is that even though there are some 42 rowspan="7" , the find_all result does not show all of them, but only 22 of them. Why?

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time
import mechanize
import cookielib

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# Want debugging messages?
#br.set_debug_http(True)
#br.set_debug_redirects(True)
#br.set_debug_responses(True)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
print "Obtaining FII data from SEBI..."
r = br.open('http://www.sebi.gov.in/sebiweb/investment/FIILatestSE.jsp?period=month')
data = r.read()
messages=[]
messages.append("FII data obtained from SEBI")
soup=BeautifulSoup(data)
list=soup.find_all(rowspan="7")
```

Comment: I ran youre code and did `print len(list)` and it printed `42`

Comment: This depends entirely on [what HTML parser is being used](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). Even different versions of lxml can give you different results of how the HTML is parsed, but if you *do* have lxml installed it is the default parser..

Comment: @ChristianCareaga it is still giving me 22

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the xml argument.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
```

For clarification, make sure you have lxml installed. If there is any other parser installed, it overrides the lxml and the parsing may not be what's expected!